# Aligning controls on the right side of the form

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a data entry form using asp.net mvc and kendo. I want to have some of the controls on the right side to. Currently if you see they are aligned on the left side. I want some on the right as well

[image]

How do I do it. Here is the code below

```
<div id="addEdit" style="width 100%; height 100%; background-color #fff;">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <ul class="fieldlist">
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">Employee Number</label>
                <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">ForeName</label>
                <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">ForeName</label>
                <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">Surname</label>
                <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">Preferred Name</label>
                <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">Language</label>
                <input id="language"  style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">Country</label>
                <input id="country" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">Preferred Name</label>
                <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>



            <li>

                <button class="k-button">Cancel</button>&nbsp;
                <button class="k-button k-primary">Save</button>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <style>
            .fieldlist {
                margin: 0 0 -2em;
                padding: 0;
            }

                .fieldlist li {
                    list-style: none;
                    padding-bottom: 2em;
                }

                .fieldlist label {
                    display: block;
                    padding-bottom: 1em;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-size: 10px;
                    color: #444;
                }
        </style>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the div wich contains the form, and add the "float:left" and "float:right" to the new ones.

```
<div style="float:left; width:40%">
    //what u want here
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:40%">
    //what u want here
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<div id="addEdit" style="width 100%; height 100%; background-color #fff;">
<div class="demo-section k-content">
    <div style="float:left; width:40%">
        <ul class="fieldlist">
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">Employee Number</label>
                <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
             // the content you want here    
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; width:40%">  
         <ul class="fieldlist">      
            <li>
                <label for="simple-input">Country</label>
                <input id="country" style="width: 40%;" />
            </li>
             // the content you want here   
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: So do you mean i need to have to UL elements and each under the div you mentioned. Could you please give me an example relevant to my code as each element is using a class

Answer (score 0):

You can make something right side in different way.
Simple is :

**System 1:**

Give a class name of that list which you want to appear in right side, then simply you can do this  class_name = right_aligned_part,

```
.fieldlist li .right_aligned_part{
    text-align: right;
}
```

And if you apply for list, then it will go all of the list in right

```
.fieldlist li{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Then, for input fields to start text in right side, just add the same code

```
input#simple-input {
   text-align: right;
}
```

**System 2:**

You can use float: right to make right any div or something

```
.fieldlist li .right_aligned_part{
    float: right;
}
```

Or, make something in left by using `float:left`

```
.fieldlist li .rightleft_aligned_part{
    float: left;
}
```

Then just add

```
clear: both
```

after class div and you can get a good result I think.